# What's special about an empty list returned from a map[string][]string

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

Here's a weird situation where I don't understand what Go is doing. I ended with some code that used the default value of map that hasn't had that key inserted into it yet.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    mmm := map[string][]string{}
    nnn := map[string][]string {
        "a": {},
    }
    
    x := mmm["a"]
    y := nnn["a"]
    z := []string{}
    
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x,y))
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x,z))
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(y,z))

    fmt.Printf("%T, %T, %T", x, y, z)
}
```

I get the unexpected output

```
false
false
true
[]string, []string, []string
```

where I would expect `true` across the board. What is it about the default value of a map that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add another printing line:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v, %#v, %#v", x, y, z)
```

It'll all become clear. It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F2nDs2solZZ)):

```
[]string(nil), []string{}, []string{}
```

`x` is a slice being `nil`, and `y` is a non-`nil` slice having `0` length, just like `z`.

Indexing a map with a key that's not in the map, it results in the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for the value type of the map. In your case the value type is `[]string`, its a slice type, and zero value for slice types is `nil`.

And [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) documents that a `nil` slice and a non-`nil`slice are not equal:

> Note that a non-nil empty slice and a nil slice (for example, []byte{} and []byte(nil)) are not deeply equal.

Answer (score 2):

First, just a quick correction, this kind of data type is called a "slice", not a "list".

When you look-up a map key that doesn't exist, you get the "zero value" of the map's value type. In the case of slices, the zero-value is a `nil` slice. A `nil` slice generally behaves much like an empty slice (for example, the `len` of a `nil` slice is zero), but they are not considered to be the same. Equality is not actually defined for slices in Go, so it is up to [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) to decide what equality means here.

You'll see this note in the documentation explaining the behaviour here:

> Slice values are deeply equal when all of the following are true: they are both nil or both non-nil, they have the same length, and either they point to the same initial entry of the same underlying array (that is, &x[0] == &y[0]) or their corresponding elements (up to length) are deeply equal. **Note that a non-nil empty slice and a nil slice (for example, []byte{} and []byte(nil)) are not deeply equal.**

Comment: yeah I'm used to thinking in java